# Retrieving List of Videos that are LIVE or Recently Live

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve a list of Live YouTube videos or recently live ones, using the API.

It currently seems to show no results when using:

[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2Cid%2Csnippet%2Cstatus&id=PLU12uITxBEPEmhVTL-lsGEgudcTUZrpCe&key={API_KEY}](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2Cid%2Csnippet%2Cstatus&id=PLU12uITxBEPEmhVTL-lsGEgudcTUZrpCe&key=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)

(I replace the API_KEY with my actual key).

Does YouTube not allow this playlist to be viewing via API access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For obtaining a list of live videos, you could use the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, queried with the following parameters:

- `order=date`,
- `eventType=live` or `eventType=completed`, and
- `type=video`.

For example, invoking the endpoint on the URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&eventType=live&type=video&maxResults=2&key=...`

I obtained the following JSON response text:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "...",
  "nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
  "regionCode": "...",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 33971,
    "resultsPerPage": 2
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "f5CCkxfKHZJT1RrihJCGx-WN5cc",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "sfEw6qe4rk8"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-12-12T23:15:22Z",
        "channelId": "UCBghEKEqODLq1qQuN7X9aTA",
        "title": "미국에서 무슨 &#39; 신내림&#39;받았는지 일요일 새벽에 군포물류창고로 총집한 거ㅣ한들!",
        "description": "This stream is created with #PRISMLiveStudio.",
        "thumbnails": {
          ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "문갑식의 진짜 TV",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "live",
        "publishTime": "2020-12-12T23:15:22Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "hWMVkmSEsnSnnN_Cj-jmqXgNZ6E",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "f7exmbx5DAc"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-12-12T23:10:53Z",
        "channelId": "UCSqEMt26wLsKC6K_wTyr9Cw",
        "title": "CyberPunk 2077 Play Through 2! type !discord",
        "description": "...",
        "thumbnails": {
          ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "Capron Funk",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "live",
        "publishTime": "2020-12-12T23:10:53Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

For what concerns your second issue -- that of playlist `PLU12uITxBEPEmhVTL-lsGEgudcTUZrpCe` -- you have to acknowledge the following misconception of yours w.r.t. to the API endpoint you're invoking:

According to the official spec of the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint, if you want to list the video metadata of a playlist identified by its ID, you should use the `playlistId` request parameter (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**`playlistId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) (string)
> The `playlistId` parameter specifies the unique *ID of the playlist* for which you want to retrieve playlist items. Note that even though this is an optional parameter, every request to retrieve playlist items must specify a value for either the `id` parameter or the `playlistId` parameter.

The `id` parameter has a completely different meaning (the emphasis below is also mine):

> [**`id`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#id) (string)
> The `id` parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more unique *playlist item IDs*.

Note that I invoked the endpoint with `playlistId=PLU12uITxBEPEmhVTL-lsGEgudcTUZrpCe` and have obtained 100 items, exactly as those to be seen on YouTube's Web UI under the URL:

`https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPEmhVTL-lsGEgudcTUZrpCe`.